# Is there a way to create code of two branches maintaining a single .repo folder

Tags: android, repository

I have done repo sync for a branch A. While doing so, I have seen repo fetching tags of other branches too. So, I think .repo will have all the versions of code of all the branches. Is it correct? If so, I wish to know if its possible to have the code of branch B without having to duplicate the .repo folder for branch B.
In other words, once I have .repo folder, I can switch the manifests, switch to another branch without contacting the server again, is it true?

Answer (score 1):

That's correct. Unless you have used repo sync -c, which fetches only the current branch, all remote branches are there.

Use `repo init -b <branchname>` to switch the manifest's branch.